# JAWS and IE 9 aren't reading the contents of the header for an accordion

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

I'm using a jQuery accordion expanded to include [the WAI-ARIA 1.0 Authoring Practices for accordions](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#accordion). The results, when using NVDA, are what I expected for all browsers. Once you focus on the header of the accordion, everything in the header is read.

When pairing IE 9 with JAWS, JAWS is reading only the first line in the header and skipping the rest of the content. JAWS, with Chrome and Firefox, is reading the header in its entirety.

The content of the header HTML:

```
<div id="accordionpanelCourse<%=Model.Id%>" class="ui-full">
<article class="ui-padLeft ui-padRight">
<div tabIndex="0" class="ItemTab iconOpen ItemTabExpanded" id="Div1" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="div1">
        <div class="imgCourseBox"></div>
        <span class=""> </span><span title="Awesome title" class="title AwesomeItemTitle">Awesome title</span>
        <div class="textActions summaryBox">
            <div>
                <span class="ui-left">Actions:</span>
                <ul class="styled">
                    <li class="styled ui-inlineBlock">
                        <a title="Unable To be Awesome" class="iconAwesome disabled" id="A1" href="javascript:void(0);" actionTarget="/Awesome/Beawesome/">&nbsp;</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="textActions summaryBox">
            <div class="ui-left">
                <span class="">Level:  </span><span title="Batman" class="textActionsBold">Batman</span>|
                <span class="">Status:  </span><span title="Attended" class="textActionsBold">Super Awesome</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Div1" class="ItemPanel" aria-labeledby="triggerAwesome<%=Model.Id%>" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0">
        <article id="contentAwesome<%=Model.Id%>"></article>
    </div>
</article>
```